Stack protection prints no backtrace
An Aarch64 binary compiled with g++ 9.3.0 and -fstack-protector-strong prints an error with
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
But it prints no backtrace neither in stderr where the above goes nor in stdout.
Is there anything else that needs to be done?
It should be noted that the build also uses ASAN.
Regards.

It's difficult to retrieve a stack trace after the stack has been smashed.
